# A method that returns string value

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to create a method(that makes labels slide to left). I've tried and researched a bit and came up with something like this.

```
public static void slidingText(string a)
{
    string first = a.Substring(1, a.Length - 1);
    string second= a.Substring(0, 1);
    a = first + second;
    return a;
}
```

However, when i use it like this(on a button etc) :

```
slidingText(label1.Text);
```

I get nothing. I have worked on it for a while and saw that i can get the text value of `label1` and change it in the method but changed value never goes out of the method. Obviously i am missing something and still couldn't figure out what i am missing.

Regards

Comment: This won't even compile. The method claims to return `void` yet you're attempting to return a `string`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways of making it work:

- Change your code take `string a` by reference, or
- Change your code to return `string`.

Here is the first solution (this will *not* work with properties):

```
public static void slidingText(ref string a)
    {
        string first = a.Substring(1, a.Length - 1);
        string second= a.Substring(0, 1);
        a = first + second;
    }
```

Here is the second solution:

```
public static string slidingText(string a)
    {
        string first = a.Substring(1, a.Length - 1);
        string second= a.Substring(0, 1);
        return first + second;
    }
```

This will require an assignment on the caller's side.

You can further optimize your code to make it a single line of code:

```
public static string slidingText(string a) {
    return a.Substring(1) + a[0];
}
```

Comment: @Heinzi Fixed :) Too much copy-paste going on.

Answer (score 4):

Just make the method return, for sample:

```
public static string slidingText(string a)
{
       string first = a.Substring(1, a.Length - 1);
       string second= a.Substring(0, 1);
       a = second + first;
       return a;
}
```

The return you need to set where you want, in `label1.Text` for sample:

```
label1.Text = slidingText(label1.Text);
```

Comment: You probably should point out the return type of the method is the culprit

Comment: For OP- You can also just "return a.Substring(#,#) + a.SubString(#,#);" but then why call this period?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, you have declared the function be of return type void, not string. Try changing that and see if it works for ya.